# generate bearer token in python

Tags: python, php, jwt, bearer-token

I have a php script which takes a user id and pass phrase to generate a bearer token. I am trying to replicate that in python. But it always gives me the 401 error. Not sure why php works and not my new python equivalent. All i want is create a bearer token based on user id and passphrase. the php script takes the elements[1]+elements[2]. I have done the same with python.

**php**

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/app/vendor/php-jwt/JWT.php';

/*
 * Acquisition date are UTC dates
 */
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
/*
 * Default values
 */
$days = 1;
$help = "\nGenerate a resto JSON Web Token (aka rJWT) authentication token for user\n";
$help  .= "\n   USAGE : generateAuthToken [options] \n";
$help .= "   OPTIONS:\n";
$help .= "          -i [bigint] : userid (mandatory)\n";
$help .= "          -d [int] : duration of token in days (default " . $days . ")\n\n";
$help .= "          -p [string] : passphrase (mandatory)\n";

$options = getopt("d:i:p:h");
/*
 * Default values
 */
$days = 1;
$options = getopt("i:d:p:h");
foreach ($options as $option => $value) {
    if ($option === "d") {
        $days = $value;
    }
    if ($option === "i") {
        $userid = $value;
    }
    if ($option === "p") {
        $passphrase = $value;
    }
}

$exp = time() + (86400 * $days);
$splitJWT = explode('.', JWT::encode(array(
    'sub' => $userid,
    'iat' => time(),
    'exp' => time() + (86400 * $days)
), $passphrase));

echo "$splitJWT[1].$splitJWT[2]";
```

**Python**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import jwt

JWT_SECRET = '<>'
JWT_ALGORITHM = 'HS256'
JWT_EXP_DELTA_SECONDS = 86400
ADMIN_USER_ID="<>"

payload = {
    'user_id': ADMIN_USER_ID,
    'exp': datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=JWT_EXP_DELTA_SECONDS)
}

print(payload)

encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(payload, JWT_SECRET , algorithm='HS256')
x = encoded_jwt.split(".")
x1 =  x[1] + "." + x[2]
print(x1)
```

Comment: Your question is not really clear. So you create a token in PHP and try to do the same in Python, but when you use the token in a call to an API, you get a 401 response. Is that right?! That means that probably the token verification failed. Do you have details regarding this? Did the signature verification fail? Or is it another reason. You wrote that you try to do the same, but actually in PHP you set a `sub` claim to userid but in Python you have `user_id` directly in the payload.

Comment: curl -X POST --header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d@<json>  "https://${RESTO_URL}/collections"                                  
This is what i try to do. I get the following error.  {"ErrorMessage":"authenticate - Unauthorized","ErrorCode":401}. I just want to replicate exactly what the php code is dong. If I were to use a sub claim and not user_id, how should the python code look like? Kindly advise. **TOKEN** is the output of the python script.